# Problems with nodejs typescript - tsconfig file

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'allowImportingTsExtensions'.

    at createTSError (/home/minh/Documents/Detech/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/minh/Documents/Detech/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at createFromPreloadedConfig (/home/minh/Documents/Detech/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:874:36)
    at phase4 (/home/minh/Documents/Detech/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:543:44)
    at bootstrap (/home/minh/Documents/Detech/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:95:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/minh/Documents/Detech/node_modules/ts-node/src/child/child-entrypoint.ts:24:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 5023 ]
}
```

This is the error when I put `allowImportingTsExtensions: true` to `tsconfig` file before run server.

If I do not put that line to `tsconfig` in, all other files I import with `*.ts` throw an error in VSCode. The server can run normally though.

Below is the error in VSCode when I don't use `allowImportingTsExtensions`

> An import path can only end with a `.ts` extension when `allowImportingTsExtensions` is enabled.

If I put it in the error in VSCode is clear but the server is crash.
If I do not, The VSCode throws an error but the server still running.

Versions:

```
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"typescript": "^4.9.4",
```

`tsconfig` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,

    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
     "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./*"],
      "@common/*": ["common/*"],
     },
      "plugins": [
        { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" }
      ],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,    
    "incremental": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "swc": true,
    "require": [ 
     "typescript-transform-paths/register",
     "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ],
    
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts","./","src/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

Comment: Are u importing code like this ```import server from './server.ts'```  instead of  ```import server from './server'``` or  ```import server from './server.js'```  ??

Comment: pretty sure `allowImportingTsExtensions` is introduced in TS v5

Comment: Install latest typescript in your package.json.  This was addressed here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75583055/visual-studio-2022-build-errors-for-typescript-modules-with-file-extensions

Comment: Yes I use import ./*.ts in all file

Comment: So I must update ts to v5 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solve the problem by update typescript to version 5. Thanks all

Comment: this could be a comment.